# changing default centos 7 workspaces

Tags: linux, centos

On CentOS7, using the gnome environment, I do not seem to be able to add, remove, or change the workspaces.

I prefer to have 2 workspaces, or no workspaces, and understand the usefulness of the feature, however, whenever I right click a workspace, it selects the workspace as active, instead of providing additional options for edits to be made as I am used to.

Comment: Good question, good answer. But the way, it works also in every Gnome Shell desktop environment (for example Fedora).

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution.

In gnome on CentOS 7, goto Applications -> Utilities -> Tweak Tool.

In the Shell portion of the Tweak Tool, you can specify 'Dynamic Workspaces' and change the number of workspaces available, including adding additional workspaces.